# Logging in automatically to Coldfusion website after logging in from windows desktop

Tags: authentication, coldfusion, identity, coldfusion-10

I have a ColdFusion 10 (CF10)  internal website that uses our AD to authenticate.

For our internal users, what would I need to do have them automatically login to our CF10 site once they log in to their workstation.

The public access is protected by MS- UAG for external users by the way. So when we go to the site now: intranet.oursite.com, it presents them with our MS-UAG login page.

Here is a screenshot of a UAG login page - https://cloudidentityblog.com/white-papers/uag-2010-custom-logon-and-logoff-pages/

My question is how do I remove that extra login page for our internal users who have logged into our network with our windows 7 workstation so they don't have to log in again through that web form?

Thank you!

Comment: This has nothing to do with ColdFusion. The authentication will be handled by the web server. You do not need to do anything special in ColdFusion. The ColdFusion pages will not be served unless the web server first establishes an authenticated connection.

Comment: Thank you @Miguel-F for your feedback.

The CF10 is just to give readers a picture of what we have done for completeness so they can see what we have done.

So how do I do the authentication setup from my windows login credentials on my windows 2008 R2 server which hosts the website internally to the website while at the same time keeping the MS-UAG login page presented to the user outside our network then?

Thank you in advance to anyone for more details on how to do this.